# Действительно ли "блин" — аналог матерного слова?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Скажите, пожалуйста, а правда ли, что слово-паразит "блин" является заменителем матерного слова в речи?
Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если слово "блин", используется в качестве междометия, то это действительно эвфемизм матерного слова, начинающегося на те же буквы. Такого же рода эвфемизмами могут быть и многие другие слова и выражения, например: *фиг, хрен, хер (буква дореформенного алфавита), бляха-муха, японский городовой, песец* и др.

Часто встречал мнение, что подобные слова для языка хуже чем мат.